# Capture data before a postback (User Control within a repeater)

Tags: vb.net, postback, preload

I have several UserControls in an ASP:Repeater. They are 'Add to basket' User Controls with a text input for quantity and a button to add the item to the basket.

My problem is the value is being reset to 1 whenever I enter a value into the quantity text box. I think this is happening because the containing page reinitialised the repeater (which holds the UserControls) and the quantity is one again before the UserControl's click event is fired.

Can anyone tell me how to capture the value in the textbox before the Postback occurs, I am happy to stick this data in a session for now.

I am thinking I need something along the lines of PreLoad? But that didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to capture the value by capturing the User Control's Unload event in the end

```
 Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
            Dim quantity As Integer
            Session("Quantity" & litProductId.Text) = If(Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, quantity), quantity, 1)
        End Sub
```

I had to also put the product id in a hidden literal as the property value seems to have gone by this point. Feels like a bit of a hack but got the job done for now. Happy to hear any other solutions